# Create columns from rows based on value of one column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
PERIOD_START_TIME       ID    temp_ID  value1  value2
06.28.2017 22:00:00     88      1        4       2
06.28.2017 22:00:00     88      2        0       7
06.28.2017 22:00:00     89      2        0       9
06.28.2017 22:00:00     89      1        5       4
06.28.2017 22:00:00     90      1        12      13
06.28.2017 22:00:00     90      2        18      4
```

Now I need to get rid of half of the rows, but get twice more columns. Actually, double column and assign temp_ID to the name of columns. Simply, temp_id transform from rows to columns.

Desired output

```
PERIOD_START_TIME    ID  value1_tpID1 vauel1_tpID2  vauel2_tpID1 value2_tpID2
06.28.2017 22:00:00  88          4       0            2            7
06.28.2017 22:00:00  89          5       0            4            9
06.28.2017 22:00:00  90          12      18           13           4

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 189604 entries, 0 to 10595
Data columns (total 12 columns):
PERIOD_START_TIME         189604 non-null object
ID                       189604 non-null int64
temp_ID                  189604 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(4), int64(6), object(2)
memory usage: 18.8+ MB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
#if necessary convert to str
df['temp_ID'] = df['temp_ID'].astype(str)
df = df.set_index(['PERIOD_START_TIME','ID','temp_ID']).unstack()
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
     PERIOD_START_TIME  ID  value1_1  value1_2  value2_1  value2_2
0  06.28.2017 22:00:00  88         4         0         2         7
1  06.28.2017 22:00:00  89         5         0         4         9
2  06.28.2017 22:00:00  90        12        18        13         4
```

Or:

```
df = df.set_index(['PERIOD_START_TIME','ID','temp_ID']).unstack()
df.columns = ['_'.join((x[0], str(x[1]))) for x in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
     PERIOD_START_TIME  ID  value1_1  value1_2  value2_1  value2_2
0  06.28.2017 22:00:00  88         4         0         2         7
1  06.28.2017 22:00:00  89         5         0         4         9
2  06.28.2017 22:00:00  90        12        18        13         4
```

If duplicates in triples `PERIOD_START_TIME`, `ID`, `temp_ID` then need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with some aggregate function like `mean`, `sum`...:

```
print (df)
     PERIOD_START_TIME  ID  temp_ID  value1  value2
0  06.28.2017 22:00:00  88        1       4       2 < same PERIOD_START_TIME  ID  temp_ID
1  06.28.2017 22:00:00  88        1       5       3 < same PERIOD_START_TIME  ID  temp_ID
2  06.28.2017 22:00:00  88        2       0       7
3  06.28.2017 22:00:00  89        2       0       9
4  06.28.2017 22:00:00  89        1       5       4
5  06.28.2017 22:00:00  90        1      12      13
6  06.28.2017 22:00:00  90        2      18       4

df = df.pivot_table(index=['PERIOD_START_TIME','ID'], 
                    columns='temp_ID', 
                    values=['value1','value2'],
                    aggfunc='mean')
df.columns = ['_'.join((x[0], str(x[1]))) for x in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
     PERIOD_START_TIME  ID  value1_1  value1_2  value2_1  value2_2
0  06.28.2017 22:00:00  88       4.5       0.0       2.5       7.0
1  06.28.2017 22:00:00  89       5.0       0.0       4.0       9.0
2  06.28.2017 22:00:00  90      12.0      18.0      13.0       4.0
```

Alternative solution:

```
df = df.groupby(['PERIOD_START_TIME','ID','temp_ID']).mean().unstack()
df.columns = ['_'.join((x[0], str(x[1]))) for x in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
     PERIOD_START_TIME  ID  value1_1  value1_2  value2_1  value2_2
0  06.28.2017 22:00:00  88       4.5       0.0       2.5       7.0
1  06.28.2017 22:00:00  89       5.0       0.0       4.0       9.0
2  06.28.2017 22:00:00  90      12.0      18.0      13.0       4.0
```

Comment: I got errors for every case, for aggrfunc for example this one: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
  Thank you

Comment: I never have problem with it, what is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: Every columns is a float

Comment: Hmm, and what another errors? I think `floats` is not problem.

Comment: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
And for the last one is : 'PERIOD_START_TIME'

Comment: Is possible add to question `print (df.info())` ? Column names can be changed if confidental. Burt it seems something is empty - is possible `df` ? Or some typo? Is possible show your code?

Comment: I have updated my question. I made a mistake, typed info later, not earlier where this need to be done.

Comment: If `df.columns = ['_'.join((x[0], str(x[1]))) for x in df.columns]` omit does it work?