# Pandas: grouping a column on a value and creating new column headings

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to re-arrange a pandas dataframe.

Presently I have:

```
id  mins  param
1   10    0.15
1   11    0.16 
1   12    0.17
2   10    0.20
2   11    0.21
2   12    0.22
```

But I would like to re-arrange and group by id to have:

```
id param_10 param_11 param_12 
1  0.15     0.16     0.17  
2  0.20     0.21     0.22
```

Is there an efficient way to do this in pandas? or should I just grind everything slowly manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and last [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = df.pivot(index='id', columns='mins', values='param').add_prefix('param_')
print (df)
mins  param_10  param_11  param_12
id                                
1         0.15      0.16      0.17
2         0.20      0.21      0.22
```

---

```
df = df.set_index(['id','mins'])['param'].unstack().add_prefix('param_')
print (df)
mins  param_10  param_11  param_12
id                                
1         0.15      0.16      0.17
2         0.20      0.21      0.22
```

If error:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

it means duplicates, need aggregation. Use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) or [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with function like `mean` ( `sum`, `median`, ...) and last [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
print (df)
   id  mins  param
0   1    10   0.15 <- id mins dupe
1   1    10   0.50 <- id mins dupe
2   1    11   0.16
3   1    12   0.17
4   2    10   0.20
5   2    11   0.21
6   2    12   0.22

df = df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='mins', values='param', aggfunc='mean')
       .add_prefix('param_')
print (df)
mins  param_10  param_11  param_12
id                                
1        0.325      0.16      0.17 <- (0.15+0.5)/2 = 0.325
2        0.200      0.21      0.22
```

---

```
df = df.groupby(['id','mins'])['param'].mean().unstack().add_prefix('param_')
print (df)
mins  param_10  param_11  param_12
id                                
1        0.325      0.16      0.17 <- (0.15+0.5)/2 = 0.325
2        0.200      0.21      0.22
```

For cleaning set `columns name` to `None` by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column `id`:

```
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
   id  param_10  param_11  param_12
0   1     0.325      0.16      0.17
1   2     0.200      0.21      0.22
```

EDIT:

Solution with multiple columns:

```
df['param1'] = df['param'] / 4
print (df)
   id  mins  param  param1
0   1    10   0.15  0.0375
1   1    10   0.50  0.1250
2   1    11   0.16  0.0400
3   1    12   0.17  0.0425
4   2    10   0.20  0.0500
5   2    11   0.21  0.0525
6   2    12   0.22  0.0550

df = df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='mins', values=['param', 'param1'], aggfunc='mean')
df.columns = ['_'.join((x[0], str(x[1]))) for x in df.columns]
print (df)
    param_10  param_11  param_12  param1_10  param1_11  param1_12
id                                                               
1      0.325      0.16      0.17    0.08125     0.0400     0.0425
2      0.200      0.21      0.22    0.05000     0.0525     0.0550
```

Comment: I will now! Thanks!

Comment: See an error ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape using 1st method...trying 2nd...

Comment: Thanks jezrael, that worked great! Can I also do this for multiple params e.g. if I have paramA and param B?

Comment: I think yes, only solution has to be a bit modified. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44822654/2901002) answer.

Comment: I add solution for it with `pivot_table`, please check it.

Comment: Brilliant!Thank you so much, jezrael