# Pandas pivot produces "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, pivot

I have a pandas table formatted as following:

```
  anger_metric  metric_name angle_value
0   71.0991 roll    14.6832
1   71.0991 yaw     0.7009
2   71.0991 pitch   22.5075
3   90.1341 roll    4.8566
4   90.1341 yaw     6.4458
5   90.1341 pitch   -10.1930
```

I need to create a view of this that pivots it to sth like this:

```
  anger_metric  roll yaw pitch 
0   71.0991     14.6832 0.7009 22.5075
1   90.1341     4.8566  6.4458 -10.1930
```

Here is my code:

```
df2= results.pivot(index='anger_metric', columns='metric_name', values='angle_value')
# results is the pnadas table/list
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

How to handle this?

Comment: Need aggregate values by `groupby` or `pivot_table` or need remove dupes by `drop_duplicates` - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11232275/2901002)

Comment: Maybe you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44847778/2901002) for better explanation of problem ans solutions.

Comment: @jezrael if that case , he should groupby and sum 1st right ?

Comment: `groupby` + some aggregate function like `mean`, `sum`, `first` - it depends of OP what need

Comment: If you have multiple values for a row-column pair, you cannot pivot. For example if you have multiple entries for row=0 and column=anger_metric  what should be in the corresponding cell? That's for you to decide. You can use an aggregation function, like mean, which is the default for pivot_table or drop the duplicates first like jezrael mentioned.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try `pivot_table`:

```
df
   anger_metric metric_name  angle_value
0       71.0991        roll      14.6832
1       71.0991         yaw       0.7009
2       71.0991       pitch      22.5075
3       90.1341        roll       4.8566
4       90.1341         yaw       6.4458
5       90.1341       pitch     -10.1930

result = df.pivot_table(index='anger_metric', 
                        columns='metric_name', 
                        values='angle_value')
result.columns.name = None

result
                pitch     roll     yaw
anger_metric                          
71.0991       22.5075  14.6832  0.7009
90.1341      -10.1930   4.8566  6.4458
```

Comment: how can the resultant view be sliced? to show the first result for example?

Comment: @A_Matar `result.iloc[0]`?

Comment: when the value is a text column, you can join the string like this.. `df.pivot_table(..., aggfunc=lambda x: ':::'.join(x)` or `first` etc.

Answer (score 2):

By using `unstack`

```
df.groupby(['anger_metric','metric_name'])['angle_value'].sum().unstack(-1)# you can using `mean` instead of `sum`
Out[433]: 
metric_name     pitch     roll     yaw
anger_metric                          
71.0991       22.5075  14.6832  0.7009
90.1341      -10.1930   4.8566  6.4458
```

Comment: why is this faster? @jezrael

Comment: Hard question, I think different implementaion of function. But it depends also of youtr real data, the best test it.