# Transforming the data from a single column into multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

Im working with a database that contains the following structure

| ID | Test | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12a | Test1 | Normal |
| 12a | Test3 | 678.2 |
| 3s5 | Test2 | <1 |
| 3s5 | Test1 | Normal |
| 8r5 | Test4 | Rectangular(3+) |

As you can see, the different tests have different result formats, and not every ID have all the tests.

I would like to transform this into something as follows:

| ID | Test1 | Test2 | Test3 | Test4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12a | Normal | *NA* | 678.2 | *NA* |
| 3s5 | Normal | <1 | *NA* | *NA* |
| 8r5 | *NA* | *NA* | *NA* | Rectangular(3+) |

I've tried with `pandas.pivot` but encountered the following error

```
df.pivot(index="ID",columns="Test",values="Result")

ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Changing the Index to ID does not work, neither resetting index.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528599/pandas-pivot-produces-valueerror-index-contains-duplicate-entries-cannot-resh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [`.pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) instead of `.pivot()`, as follows:

```
df.pivot_table(index="ID", columns="Test", values="Result", aggfunc='first')
```

**Result:**

```
Test   Test1 Test2  Test3            Test4
ID                                        
12a   Normal   NaN  678.2              NaN
3s5   Normal    <1    NaN              NaN
8r5      NaN   NaN    NaN  Rectangular(3+)
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried using `pivot_table` but was missing `aggfunc="first"` argument. Works like a charm!

Comment: @Mario_B   Without the `aggfunc="first"` argument, the default is `aggfunc='mean'` which requires numeric values to work properly.  As your data contains non-numeric data, using `aggfunc="first"` is a trick to make `pivot_table()` work for this kind of data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of doing it :

```
df = {'ID': ['12a', '12a', '3s5', '3s5', '8r5'],
  'Test': ['Test1', 'Test3', 'Test2', 'Test1', 'Test4'],
  'Result': ['Normal', '678.2', '<1', 'Normal', 'Rectangular(3+)']}

df=df.groupby(['ID', 'Test'])['Result'].sum().unstack(fill_value="NA")
```